# Could not connect: Access denied for user shout1@localhost (using password:YES) 'Error PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a script set up on a site which is a static shoutbox page for people to leave comments etc.

Everthing /was/ working fine.  I have set up my constants in my shoutbox.php file as such;

```
define("HOST", "localhost"); 
define("USER", "shout1");
define("PASSWORD", "xxxxxxxx"); 
define("DB", "shout1");
```

My database is called shout1 and the user name assigned to it is the same.  I have created a table on that database called shoutbox which has 4 entries of id (INT), date, user (VARCHAR) & message (VARCHAR) which I believe is fine.

When I go to the domain in question http://p4blo.it/shoutbox I get the error mentioned in the title advising that access is denied @localhost for shout1

Any ideas?  I have double and triple checked, deleted DB and tables, recreated etc.

EDIT:  Forgot to mention, user shout1 has been assigned access with FULL privileges to database shout1

Comment: Maye sure `shout1` is granted access to `shout1.*`. _See [GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html)_

Comment: Sorry, edited the Q, forgot to add that shout1 user has been given full access to shout1 DB with full privileges

Comment: Can you post your grant statement you executed? (blocking out any credential information of course).

Comment: I didnt execute a statement. I set up the databases, users and permissions through my hosting control panel like I usually do.

Comment: I would venture to say that there is no password assigned to the account.  If there is, try going in to your control panel and re-assigning (or changing it).

Comment: Hi Brad, definitely is a password assigned to user shout1.  I have added my own, I have used a randomly generated one through control panel, i have deleted the DB and made a new one with new password. Pretty much every permutation you can think of haha. It is really flummoxing me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your host runs with cPanel. In cPanel you have to be carefull with your user and database names, since they are prefixed with your cPanel-username. Eg. if your cPanel-username is "p4blo" then the database is called "p4blo_shout1" and the username "p4blo_shout1".

Comment: you sir are a life saver.  Yes, the database was prefixed with my login for cPanel. I have changed the php file, all is working now :) Thank you kindly